# Why colums in SELECT not belongs to SELECT

Tags: sql

I have this select, but does not work.

```
select
    a.code1,
    a.data1,
    a.stval,
    (select sum(col1+col2+col3) from tad ) as sum1,
    (select sum(col7+col8+col9) from tbac) as sum2,
    CASE
        WHEN (sum1+sum2) > 100 THEN (a.stval * sum1) 
        WHEN (sum1+sum2( <= 100 THEN (a.stval * sum2)
       END as newdat1
    from arti as a
```

Where is the error?  why (sum1+sum2) its  error?

Thanks

Comment: This `(sum1+sum2(` should be this `(sum1+sum2)`. Also, you may need to check if a value is null with `IFNULL()`.

Comment: BTW you are using `sum(col1+col2+col3)` while it's working it's unnecessary - use just `sum(col1,col2,col3)` or `col1+col2+col3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific reason is that SQL is a descriptive language that does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  This is true in the `select` clause.  This is true in the `where` clause.  It is true in the `from` clause.  SQL *describes* what the results look like.  It does not *prescribe* the specific actions.

As a result, SQL does not allow identifiers defined in the `select` to be used in the same `select` clause (nor in the `where` clause at the same level).  The expressions can be processed in any order.

The normal solution in your case is to use a subquery or a CTE.  In your case, though, the subqueries are independent of the outer query (as written), so I would move them to the `from` clause:

```
select a.code1, a.data1, a.stval, x1.sum1, x2.sum2,
       (CASE WHEN x1.sum1 + x2.sum2 > 100 THEN a.stval * x1.sum1 
             WHEN x1.sum1 + x2.sum2 <= 100 THEN a.stval * x2.sum2
        END) as newdat1
from arti a cross join
     (select sum(col1+col2+col3) as sum1 from tad ) x1 cross join
     (select sum(col7+col8+col9) as sum2 from tbac) x2;
```

EDIT:

You can use a subquery or CTE.  But there is an approach that builds on the above:

```
select a.code1, a.data1, a.stval, x1.sum1, x2.sum2,
       (CASE WHEN x1.sum1 + x2.sum2 > 100 THEN a.stval * x1.sum1 
             WHEN x1.sum1 + x2.sum2 <= 100 THEN a.stval * x2.sum2
        END) as newdat1
from arti a join
     (select ascon, sum(col1+col2+col3) as sum1
      from tad
      group by ascon
     ) x1
     on x1.ascon = arti.code1 cross join
     (select sum(col7+col8+col9) as sum2 from tbac) x2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it Works. But i need to add :  "where tad.ascon=arti.code1" here :
.....

     (select sum(col1+col2+col3) as sum1 from tad where tad.ascon=arti.code1) x1 cross join
.....
but show error (red underline)

Comment: Excúseme, I dont understand how to join "code1" with "ascon" ?

Comment: Hi Gordon, i understand the SELECT you did, and work, but dont work for me, table arti has 6500 rows ( unique "code1") and table TAD has more tan 400,000 rows . When SELECT is generated, must has 6500 rows (same rows arti table) , but real generated has more tan 2000000 rows , I just stop the query.

Answer (score 2):

(sum1 + sum2) is an error because these identifiers are not defined in the scope where you are trying to use them. In an SQL select list, you cannot use symbols declared in the same select list, irrespective of their position on the list. Use a subquery if you need to access sum1 and sum2.